# ncftpput resume upload

Tags: shell, ftp

I need a unidirectional syncronicazion bewteen local host and remote ftp host with a sh script.
I'm using NCFTPPUT with -z argument, but seems that it sends all files and not only added or edited.
Do you know how ncftpput works with "-z" argument? I thought it compares timestamps or filesize, but I still don't unserstand why it overwrites all files with same filesize and with a earlier timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ncftpput -z argument doesn't work when applied -T suffix argument